# Updating multiple records fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I update multiple records in SQL Server 2008? I wanted to run the following query but it failed:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET type = 1 WHERE type is NULL
```

Comment: Is your table actually named `TABLE`? If you, you'll need to escape it by writing `UPDATE [TABLE]`. Otherwise, some more information would help. Failed how? Please post the error message and your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
Update T
SET type = 1
FROM [Table] as T
WHERE type IS NULL
```

Comment: [SQL] Update T
SET type = 1
FROM TABLE as T
WHERE type IS NULL

[Err] 21000 - [SQL Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
01000 - [SQL Server]The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @user1029829 are you posting your full query? Please provide some more details in your question.

Comment: Yes, this is my full query.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `TABLE` with `[TABLE]` (in brackets)?

Comment: Oh, is it because I have some triggers set?

Comment: @user1029829 Yep, that'd do it. It's important to always write triggers on the assumption that multiple rows could be passed to them at once.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe you have a trigger on the [Table] that is failing.  This can often happen because the Trigger isn't designed to handle multiple updates at one time.  If there is a trigger on the table, make sure it is using the INSERTED and DELETED tables properly.